# slider AutoToolTip always on

Tags: wpf

I'm brand new to wpf. I have a window with multiple sliders and I want to display the value of the slider adjacent to the thumb how AutoToolTipPlacement behaves, except that I want it to always be visible.

I've tried a few different approaches to this but none are working out quite right.

Solution

```
<Track.Thumb>
<Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="18" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="11">
    <Thumb.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M0,0C0,0 11,0 11,0 11,0 11,18 11,18 11,18 0,18 0,18 0,18 0,0 0,0z" Fill="#FFF0F0F0" Stretch="Fill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="#FFACACAC" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="-12,-23,-13,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" TextAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFDCECFC"/>
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFDAECFC"/>
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Thumb.Template>
</Thumb>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own template for that. Here is a more general article on slider templates in WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256.aspx. Also, here you can find a more specific example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18270/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-3-Data-binding.

Comment: Thank you for trying to address my question.  My problem was that I wasn't adding the textbox in the correct location nor using the proper bindings.